# Combining many Stata files to one data frame in R

Tags: r, dataframe, purrr

I'm trying to combine many Stata files from The European Social Survey into one data frame in R. The Stata files are from different years and are stored in different folders that follow a certain logic - 'C:\data\ess\2002', 'C:\data\ess\2004', and so on. The files, however, don't have consistent names. But they all have the same variables of interest to me. For each file I want to compute weighted averages over countries and add information about year in the following way:

```
library(tidyverse)
library(haven)
ess2002 <- read_dta("C:/data/ESS/2002/ESS1e06_4.dta") %>% 
    select(cntry, pspwght, starts_with('ppl') ) %>% 
    group_by(cntry) %>% 
        summarize(ppltrst = weighted.mean(ppltrst, pspwght, na.rm = TRUE),  
                  pplfair = weighted.mean(pplfair, pspwght, na.rm = TRUE), 
                  pplhlp = weighted.mean(pplhlp, pspwght, na.rm = TRUE)) %>% 
    mutate(year = 2002)
```

Then I want to combine this for all years into one data frame by appending the data frames, e.g. `ess <- bind_rows(ess2002, ess2004, ...)`. This approach works fine, but it's not that elegant. I assume I can store the file names and the years in vectors and loop over them or use purrr in some way, but I haven't figured out how. One problem is that I would prefer to not have all the full Stata datasets in the memory at the same time, so I would like to select the relevant variables from one file before reading in the next file.

Could anyone help me find a more elegant solution? Any help would be greatly appreciated.

Comment: Sorry, I should have opened that door by using the word 'elegant', but I would still appreciate any suggestion on how to find a solution with a loop or by using purrr.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To use `purrr` for this, you could generalize your aggregation steps into a single function:

```
summarize_dta <- . %>%
    read_dta() %>% 
    select(cntry, pspwght, starts_with('ppl') ) %>% 
    group_by(cntry) %>% 
        summarize(ppltrst = weighted.mean(ppltrst, pspwght, na.rm = TRUE),  
                  pplfair = weighted.mean(pplfair, pspwght, na.rm = TRUE), 
                  pplhlp = weighted.mean(pplhlp, pspwght, na.rm = TRUE))
```

Then create a tibble or dataframe with one column each for year and corresponding .dta file (`file_name`).  Then you should be able to do this:

```
df %>% 
    mutate(data = map(file_name, summarize_dta)) %>%
    unnest()
```

Comment: I think you meant to write "purrrr-fectly"